# Если нет материала в БД по определенному критерию

Tags: база-данных, mysql

```
$rand = rand(1, 3);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `tid` FROM `tasks` WHERE `tprice` = $rand");
```

Вот проблема в следующем:

> > если в базе данных нет tprice = 2, а rand выпал именно на 2, то запрос вернёт пустоту.

Как это можно обойти? То есть если rand попался 2 и в базе нет tprice = 2, то выводить например что-то другое. Допустим tprice > 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[[@klopp](/users/6550/klopp)](/users/6550/klopp), насколько помню, RAND() в ORDER BY будет вызываться для каждой строки, т.е. если записей куча - на вычисление RAND, а затем на сортировку будет уходить куча времени.

[[@sergiks](/users/7161/sergiks)](/users/7161/sergiks),

```
SELECT DISTINCT tprice FROM ...
$rand = array_rand( $tprices);
SELECT `tid` FROM `tasks` WHERE `tprice` = $rand
```

Опять же - если записей куча, то $tprices будет весить много, да и все записи выбираться слишком долго будут.

[[@ModaL](/users/6646/modal)](/users/6646/modal), можно попробовать:

```
SELECT COUNT(`tid`) AS CNT FROM `tasks` WHERE `tprice` BETWEEN 1 AND 3
$rand = rand(0, CNT);
SELECT `tid` FROM `tasks` WHERE `tprice` BETWEEN 1 AND 3 LIMIT $rand, 1
```

Т.е. получаем число записей удовлетворяющих условию, получаем случайное число в пределах от 0 до максимума, а затем выбираем один удовлетворяющий условию элемент с позиции $rand.

Единственное, не знаю как повлияет BETWEEN на скорость

Comment: Ну, мы всех условий не знаем, как обычно :) Можно вообще выбрать по between (с лимитом или без), а из полученного массива выбирать уже не прибегая к базе.

Comment: @sergiks, точно... Раз мы получаем $tprices, то почему бы не добавить в SELECT еще и tid? Тогда не надо будет второго обращения к БД. Но все равно - зачем получать лишнее, огромное и медленное?

Comment: > если записей куча, то $tprices будет весить много, да и все записи выбираться слишком долго будут.

Мы не знаем, может, записей всего 10. Если куча, можно набор уникальных tprices поместить во временную таблицу, напр. с `engine=Memory`, и решить задачу целиком на стороне SQL. И, конечно же, нужен индекс по колонке `tprice`, раз такие запросы интересуют — всё будет летать.

Answer (score 0):

Уточните: запрос может вернуть несколько строк, или tprice уникален? Записей миллионы, или всего десяток?

В общем случае надо получить сначала массив существующих значений `tprice`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT tprice FROM ...
```

а затем выбрать случайный из них:

```
$rand = array_rand( $tprices);
```

и выбрать записи с этим tprice:

```
SELECT `tid` FROM `tasks` WHERE `tprice` = $rand
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `tid` FROM `tasks` WHERE `tprice` BETWEEN 1 AND 3 ORDER BY RAND()
```